# Other clients not be blocked while the transaction is executing in redis?

Tags: go, redis

Code:

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })
    pipe := rdb.TxPipeline()
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        pipe.Set(ctx, "a", "abc", time.Second)
    }
    fmt.Println("Start")
    pipe.Exec(ctx)
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

When the console prints `Start`, it means that the transaction has started to execute. Then I try to connect to redis in the shell and execute a `get` command, why the command is not blocked? (At this point `End` has not been printed). Is this normal, as I understand the command should be blocked?  Because the command in the transaction has not been executed yet

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get a
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Because that’s how transactions work? The data is not committed until the transaction is complete. If you want a lock, then you can build a distributed lock on redis too.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Starting a transaction on Redis will not lock anything on the server. What happens when you call EXEC is that all the the queued commands will be execute atomically.

The only locking provided is with the WATCH command, which will fail the transaction if any of the WATCHed keys are modified.

You can read more about Redis transactions [here](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/).